# dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure)

Tags: debian, apt, kali-linux, package-management, dpkg

fontconfig issues

```
# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up font config (2.13.1-4.5) ...
Regenerating fonts cache... failed.
See /var/log/fontconfig.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure):
 installed font config package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fontconfig
```

```
# cat /var/log/fontconfig.log
fc-cache: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Transform
```

[image]

According to the log output, I ran the command to downgrade the libharfbuzz* package from version 5.2.0-2 to 2.7.4-1, but it can't be managed without fixing the fontconfig issue.

```
# apt install libharfbuzz*=2.7.4-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libharfbuzz0' for glob 'libharfbuzz*'
Note, selecting 'libharfbuzz-icu0' for glob 'libharfbuzz*'
Note, selecting 'libharfbuzz-gobject0' for glob 'libharfbuzz*'
Note, selecting 'libharfbuzz0a' for glob 'libharfbuzz*'
Note, selecting 'libharfbuzz0b' for glob 'libharfbuzz*'
Note, selecting 'libharfbuzz-bin' for glob 'libharfbuzz*'
Note, selecting 'libharfbuzz-dev' for glob 'libharfbuzz*'
Note, selecting 'libharfbuzz-doc' for glob 'libharfbuzz*'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up font config (2.13.1-4.5)
Regenerating fonts cache... failed.
See /var/log/fontconfig.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure):
 installed fontconfig package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fontconfig
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

Check for manually compiled old versions of libfreetype which is usually provided by the libfreetype6 package.

I had and older version compiled in /usr/local/lib which not only broke the fontconfig but as e result of the broken fontconfig, the update-initramfs has been broken too.